# FileReader fails to preview picture taken on Google Chrome for Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3. I'm using google chrome to upload a picture taken by the device camera directly to my custom web application.

If I upgrade my google chrome version to the latest, It wont show the preview. The file reader throws a "NotFoundError". But when I downgrade to the default version it works perfectly

Here you can reproduce the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/z3andbwh/1/

HTML:

```
<img alt="preview" id="image-preview" class="img-responsive hidden" />
<input type="file" accept='image/*' capture="camera" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('input[type="file"]').change(function(){
  var input = this;
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#image-preview').attr('src', e.target.result).removeClass('hidden');
    }
    reader.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
});
```

Google Chrome version: 38.0.2125.102

I don't know the default google chrome version the tablet is shipped with.

**UPDATE:**

Making more test with other devices, It works as it should. The only device I have tested and it doesn't work is the Galaxy Tab 3 8.0"

Comment: I am seeing the same problem.

Comment: I'm getting the same NotFoundError on my Samsung Galaxy 3 running Chrome 38.0.2125.114. How did you fix?

Comment: I have not fixed it yet, I downgraded my google chrome version.

Comment: It is fixed on version 39 (released today Nov 13)